# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ssl

Tags: python, dll, anaconda

if I run the following code:

```
# -*- coding: cp852 -*-
import sys
sys.modules[__name__].__dict__.clear()

import os
import tweepy as tw
import pandas as pd
```

I get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\tweep\tweep.py", line 6, in 
> import tweepy as tw   File "C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy_*init*_.py",
> line 18, in 
> from tweepy.streaming import Stream, StreamListener   File "C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py",
> line 13, in 
> import ssl   File "C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in 
> import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ssl: Das
> angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

I just reinstalled the Anaconda environment because of an other issue. Any help would be appreciated. The last sentence in the error message is German and reads: *The specified module can not be found.*

Best

Daniel